# How does a wallet integrate dex protocols?

Tags: wallets, decentralized-exchange

How can a standard wallet with no exchange feature integrate dex protocols that allow users to swap ETH and ERC20 tokens within the app?

I know there are some dex protocols out there but which protocol allows developers to integrate the dex feature easily and reliably?

Answer (score 1):

A dex protocol is made up of smart contracts. So the 'standard wallet' would need suitable UI to interact with the underlying functionality of the smart contracts for the dex protocol to be integrated into the wallet. 
There are many examples of dex protocols out there in the wildness, have a look at ether delta: https://github.com/etherdelta/smart_contract/blob/master/etherdelta.sol